# выборка из бызы данных по соответствию сравнению начальных символов строки

Tags: mysql, sql, mysqli

Доброго времени, задача такова - есть база данных в ней лежать 16ти значные числа типа 4405625225299877 надо сделать выборку только тех строк которые начинаются с определенных 8-10 символов к примеру выбрать все строки в которых первые 9 символов 440562522 можно конечно так

```
 $numb = "440562522";
 $tmp = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE LOCATE(lower('".$numb."'), lower(numbers))");
```

но это не дает же нужной точности, есть ли способ сделать так что бы было точне что бы как то считало с начала строки - вроде регулярного выражения в sql

Comment: `SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE column LIKE "440562522%";` не подходит?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский сейчас попробуем

Answer (score 3, accepted):

По-моему  вы ищите обыкновенный [LIKE](http://www.mysql.ru/docs/man/String_comparison_functions.html) - функция производит сравнение с шаблоном, используя операции сравнения простых регулярных выражений в SQL. Возвращает 1 (ИСТИНА) или 0 (ЛОЖЬ).

```
$numb = "440562522";
$tmp = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE column LIKE "'.$numb.'%"');
```

что такое `%` ?

Выражение `LIKE` предусматривает использование следующих двух шаблонных символов:

- Символ `%`   соответствует любому количеству символов, даже нулевых.
- Символ `_`   соответствует ровно одному символу.

Соответственно если есть строка `рахамбахарамамбуру`, то если ищем `рахам` и нам неважно что идёт далее, то это будет как

`SELECT * FROM table WHERE col LIKE "рахам%"`.

Или если ищем `мам` и нам неважно что идёт впереди и далее, то это будет как

`SELECT * FROM table WHERE col LIKE "%мам%"`

и т.д.

С подчеркиванием можно также ознакомиться в справке.